# const_cast doesn't change the value

Tags: c++

After `const_cast`, the value does not change in the main function. But changes when calling an external function, still prints the old value in the main (where `const int` is initialized first).

```
int main() {
    const int i = 5;
    int* p = const_cast<int*>(&i);
    *p = 22;
    std::cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is `5`, why? The watch-window shows value of `i = 22`:

[image: Watch-window value]

So why does it print 5 ? The output differs if I call an external function:

```
void ChangeValue(const int i) {
    int* p = const_cast<int*>(&i);
    *p = 22;
    std::cout<<i; //Here the value changes to 22
}

int main() {
    const int i = 5;
    ChangeValue(i); //Value changes to 22 in the ChangeValue function
    std::cout<<i // It again prints 5.
}
```

Why is the value not changed even if the value changes after calling the `ChangeValue` function?

I get the same output on a Linux Platform. Could someone please add clarity to my confusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to modify a constant value leads to *undefined behavior*, just don't do it.

As for why it doesn't change, the compiler sees that it is a compile-time constant and may store it in a read-only segment. It could also be because the compiler know the value is constant, and is using the actual value in the generated code, instead of reading the variable.

---

For the second program, the variable `i` can't be stored in a read-only segment, it's stored on the stack like any other local variable. However, since you marked `i` as constant attempting to modify it is *still* undefined behavior.

The reason the `main` program prints the old value, is because you pass the variable *by value* meaning it gets copied into the local variable `i` in the `ChangeValue` function. If the variable wasn't a constant in the `main` or the `ChangeValue` function, the value of `i` in the `main` function would *still* not change.

If you change the `ChangeValue` function to take its argument by reference, you might get the same behavior as the first program.

Comment: *"may store it in a read-only segment"* - that would likely cause a SIGSEGV or similar; seeing "5" printed is more plausibly related to the compiler not updating its internal records of the value of `i` when encountering the attempted write (it's under no obligation to model impact of code with *undefined behaviour*), and, for `cout << i`, using the original unchanged record of the value to load the register or stack position expected by `<<(std::ostream&, int)`.